# How to get back to the top of a trie structure

Tags: c, trie, cs50

I am working on CS50, and fighting a bit with my understanding of pointers/tries. 
I am currently trying to load multiple words from a file into active memory.
Whenever the loading loop hits a "\n", I want to return to the top (root) of the trie to start loading a new word in. 
I am not sure how to do so. 
I would be grateful for any pointers /heh/.

```
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{

 // create root for trie
 //set all children to NULL
 node *root;
 root = malloc(sizeof(node));
 for (int leaves=0; leaves<53; leaves++)
    {
        root ->children[leaves] = NULL;
    }

 //defining an int for the children[x] structure and a char for ever letter to read in
 int children_position=0;
 char * letter = malloc(1);

 //open file 
  FILE *inptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", dictionary);
        return false;
    }

   //find size of file

    fseek(inptr, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int size_of_file = ftell(inptr);
    fseek(inptr, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    //loop through dictionary starts here

for (int pointer_position=0; pointer_position<size_of_file; pointer_position++)
{

    //read dictionary one char at the time
    fread(letter,1,1,inptr);

    //if letter is '\'' 

     if (*letter=='\'')
    {
         children_position =52;

//move to next level if path already exists
if (root->children[children_position]!=NULL)
          {
              fprintf(stderr, "children[children_position] exists already \n");
              root = root ->children[children_position];
              break;
          }

          //else create new node 
          else
          {
            fprintf(stderr, "new node created\n");
            node * newnode;
            newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
            root ->children[children_position] = newnode;
            for (int leaves=0; leaves<53; leaves++)
            {
                newnode ->children[leaves] = NULL;
            }
            newnode->is_word=false;
            root = root ->children[children_position];
            break;
          }
    }

    //if letter is /n set is_word to true
    if (*letter=='\n')
    {
         root->is_word =true;
         // bring root back to original pointer;
    }

    //if letter is an lower case character
   if (islower(*letter))
    {
         children_position = *letter -97;

         //move to next level if path already exists
          if (root->children[children_position]!=NULL)
          {
              fprintf(stderr, "children[children_position] exists already \n");
              root = root ->children[children_position];
              break;
          }

          //else create new node
          else
          {
            fprintf(stderr, "new node created\n");
            node * newnode;
            newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
            root ->children[children_position] = newnode;
            for (int leaves=0; leaves<53; leaves++)
            {
                newnode ->children[leaves] = NULL;
            }
            newnode->is_word=false;
            root = root ->children[children_position];
            break;
          }
    }


    //if letter is a upper case character
     if (isupper(*letter))
    {
         children_position = *letter- 65+26;

         //move to next level if path already exists
         if (root->children[children_position]!=NULL)
          {
              fprintf(stderr, "children[children_position] exists already \n");
              root = root ->children[children_position];
              break;
          }

           //else create new node
          else
          {
            fprintf(stderr, "new node created\n");
            node * newnode;
            newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
            root ->children[children_position] = newnode;
            for (int leaves=0; leaves<53; leaves++)
            {
                newnode ->children[leaves] = NULL;
            }
            newnode->is_word=false;
            root = root ->children[children_position];
            break;
          }
    }

}

 fclose(inptr); 
return true;
}
```

My struct is defined in the header file as follows:

```
typedef struct node
{
    bool is_word;
    struct node *children[53];
}
node;
```

Comment: Given that your nodes do not have pointers to their parents, the only way to return to the root is to have some external pointer to it.  In your particular case, I suggest that you avoid modifying the `root` pointer once set, and instead use a different variable to track the current node as you load words.  Then `root` will always refer to the root.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. 
I thought to add a:
node *temp;
and then set
*temp=root;
But I have a mental block there, I think.
If I do the whole loop with temp instead of root, wouldn't root have none of the info that I changed with the help of temp?
Basically, how can I have 2 pointers to the same "location" so that the info at the location is accessible by 2 pointers?

Comment: You can have as many pointers as you want to a particular memory location. They are just variables. Can't two variables hold the same value like 123?

Comment: Oh that is true. Sorry completely blanked there for a moment. :)